# pm2 script variable when script path is not within executing folder

Tags: process-management

I have a pm2 json file that contains a script element. However on the box in question, the target is not within the pm2 script folder.
the documentation says that the path needs to be relative to pm2 start.

So if pm2 start is in var/opt/folder/

but my script is in /usr/java
how do I set the script parameter.
I have tried things like ~/usr/java and ../../../usr/java, which work from the terminal, but don't work as a pm2 script parameter